# Learning about the sustain pedal modification

Tags: keyboard-pedals

Can a keyboard be damaged later on when you use a homemade sustain pedal on it? Is it necessary to put a resistor in a sustain pedal?

Comment: What make, what model?

Answer (score 2):

I have used various switching pedals as sustain on various keyboards. There has never seemed to be a problem with using something as simple as a bell-push to activate sustain on any. Best to check what the *original* pedal actually does. It could be a momentary make/break, like a bell-push, or a switching mode, working like a light switch. More likely the former, with nothing needed more than a bit of wire shorting another.

Comment: Some keyboards don't even care which way round the switch works, they analyse at boot. If it detects a closed contact, it assumes open to activate & vice versa.